# Installing qutebrowser

Tags: openssl, i3-wm, tox

Could someone guide me installing qutebrowser on Ubuntu? [Installing qutebrowser with tox](https://www.qutebrowser.org/INSTALL.html#tox) has the process I must follow to install it, but I don't know what to do after executing:

```
$ tox -e mkvenv-pypi
```

I tried searching, but I guess its a little complicated.

Comment: Just create a script file in `/usr/local/bin/qutebrowser` to open qutebrowser as any other application from anywhere.

#!/bin/bash
~/path/to/qutebrowser/.venv/bin/python3 -m qutebrowser "$@"

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 it’s recommended to install qutebrowser via tox instead in order to be able to use the new QtWebEngine backend.
Assuming, you are using one of above version.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser.git
$ cd qutebrowser
$ tox -e mkvenv-pypi
$ vim /usr/local/bin/qutebrowser

#!/bin/bash
~/path/to/qutebrowser/.venv/bin/python3 -m qutebrowser "$@"
```

`/path/to/qutebrowser/` is your current directory. `pwd` will show you that.

`$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/qutebrowser`

Now you can open *qutebrowser* like any other applications.

Comment: Thanx a lot. I was confused about the "openssl" thing.

Comment: it says command not found

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: When I try to type qutebrowser in the terminal I get this error:
bash: /usr/local/bin/qutebrowser: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

You need to type:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/qutebrowser
```

Comment: You should make it clear that the use of this command provides the necessary user permissions to run the application after it has been installed following the instructions  provided in the answer provided by @kevy.